# JavaScript forces you to double click in order to get the drop down menu to open or close

Tags: javascript

```html
<html><head>
  <title>J.T.C.</title>
  <meta charset="utf-16">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/mainsd2B.css">
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- Scroll -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo:460|Ramabhadra|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

                                                                                                   
                                                                                                    
         <!--  Adjust top of navbar -->                                                                                           
         <script type="text/javascript">
            var sw = document.getElementById('side-menu');
   window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
   sw.style.width = '0px';
   });
  </script>

    
   <script type="text/javascript">
var s = document.getElementById('side-menu');
function resizeFunction() {
    s.style.display = 'none';
}

  window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
  </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Reset Navbar  top afer scroll
            $(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
   var $nav = $(".navbar-fixed-top");
   $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
 });
}); 
            </script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
    //Control side-nav top position
           $(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
   var $nav1 = $(".side-nav-fixed-top");
   $nav1.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav1.height());
      $nav1.visibility= "hidden";
 });
}); 
       </script> 
       
<script type="text/javascript">
// Show Hide Navbar UL List
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(document).scrollTop() > 200){//Here 200 may be not be exactly 200px
    $('.side-nav').hide();
  }
});

</script>
<style>
  @media screen and (max-width: 927px) {
   .navbar {
    overflow: visible;
   }
  }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body  onresize="resizeFunction()" >

  <!-- Wrapper -->
   <div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Header -->
     <header id="header" class="alt">
      <span class="logo"><img src="/assets/css/images/header46.jpg" alt=""></span>
     </header>
      
    <!-- Nav -->
     <nav id="nav">
      <div id="mainconm"><img src="/assets/css/images/mainltx.png" alt=""></div>
      
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#intro" class="">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#first" class="active active-locked">Section One</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="">Social</a>
            <ul>
         <li><a href="#second" class="">Section Two</a></li>
        
         <li><a href="#third" class="" >Section Three</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#" class="">Course</a>
         <ul>
         <li><a href="#forth" class="">Section Four</a></li> 
        
         <li><a href="#fifth" class="" >Sections Five</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
     </nav>
     
                   <div id="sticky-anchor"></div>

<!-- class="navbar" -->
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id="navigation" onscroll="navtotop()">
                     
    <span class="open-slide"> 
        <button id="menu-box" onclick="toggle_visibility()"><svg width="30" height="30">
            <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#000" stroke-width="3"></path>
            <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#000" stroke-width="3"></path>
            <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#000" stroke-width="3"></path>
        </svg></button> 

    </span>
  
<div id="side-menu" class="side-nav side-nav-fixed-top bg-primary" style="display: none; width: 0px;">
 <span class="open-slide">
   <div style="height:70px; width: 100%; background:rgb(6, 13, 19, 1)" > 
        <button id="menu-box" style=" background: #000; border-radius: 0;" onclick="toggle_visibility()"><svg width="30" height="30">
            <path d="M0, 3 30,25" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3"></path>
            <path d="M0,25 60,-17" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3"></path>
        </svg>
  </button> 
   </div>

    </span>  
                          
                            <a href="#top" class="slide" onclick="toggle_visibility()">Home</a>
       <a href="#first" class="slide" >Section One</a>
       <a href="#second" class="slide" >Section Two</a>
       <a href="#third" class="slide" >Section Three</a>
       <a href="#forth" class="slide" >Section Four</a>
       <a href="#fifth" class="slide" >Section Five</a>
                            <a href="#seventh" class="slide" >Section Six</a>
  </div>
<div id="conm"><img  src="assets/css/images/mainltx.png" alt=""></div>

 
  </nav><div id="intro" style="position: absolute; z-index: 8000; top: 100px;"></div>

  


    <!-- Main -->
     <div id="main">

   
      <!-- Introduction -->
       <section class="main" style="padding-top: 20px !important;">
        <div class="spotlight">
         <div class="content">
          <div id="largeicon" >
          <span class="image"><img src="assets/css/images/homeimage.png" alt=""></span>
          </div>
          <div id="smallicon" class="alt">
           <span class="logo"><img src="/assets/css/images/smallbanner.png" alt=""></span>
          </div>  
          <header class="major">
           <h3>Help us help you. Please take the surveys below.</h3>
          </header>
          <div style="float: clear;"></div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </section>

      <!-- First Section -->
       <section id="first" class="main special">
        <header class="major">
    
        </header>
        <div id="contact" class="sticky slide" ><a href="#seventh">Contact Us</a></div>

        
       <span class="image"><img style="width: 100%;" src="/assets/css/images/jb.png" alt=""></span>
        <div id="coach" class="center-list">
            
        </div>
        <footer class="major">
         
        </footer>
       </section>

      <!-- Second Section -->
      
       <section id="second" class="main special apcol">
        <header class="major">
         <span class="image"><img style="width: 100%;" src="/assets/css/images/ps.png" alt=""></span>
        <div class="center-list" style="margin-top: .05em;">
            
        </div>
        <footer class="major">
         
        </footer>
       </header></section>

       <!-- Third Section -->
       <section id="third" class="main special">
        <header class="major">
    
        </header>
       <span class="image"><img style="width: 100%;" src="/assets/css/images/lt-icon.jpg" alt=""></span>
        <div class="center-list">
           
        </div>
        <footer class="major">
         
        </footer>
       </section>

       <!-- Forth Section -->
       <section id="forth" class="main special">
        <header class="major">
    
        </header>
       <span class="image"><img style="width: 100%;" src="/assets/css/images/cting.jpg" alt=""></span>
        <div class="center-list">
            
        </div>
        <footer class="major">
         
        </footer>
       </section>

       <!-- Fifth Section -->
       <section id="fifth" class="main special inactive">
        <header class="major">
    
        </header>
       <span class="image"><img style="width: 100%;" src="/assets/css/images/vt.jpg" alt=""></span>
        <div class="center-list">
            
        </div>
        <footer class="major">
         
        </footer>
       </section>

     </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div id="seventh" class="inactive"></div>
     <footer id="footer">
      <section>
       
      </section>
      <section>
       <dl class="alt">
      </section>
    
     </footer>

   </div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
   <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
          
  
<script type="text/javascript">

// Toggle close with button
var s = document.getElementById('side-menu');
function toggle_visibility() {
if(s.style.width == '0px')
s.style.width = '300px';
else
s.style.width = '0px';
}
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
// Smooth Scroll
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $('.slide').click(function() {
  
  var link = $(this).attr('href');
  
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(link).offset().top}, 2000);
  return false; 
 });
});


// toggle close ul after select from list

document.getElementById('side-menu').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0';
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#side-menu").show();
  });
  $("#side-menu a").on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#side-menu")
      .show()
    /*  .siblings() */
      .val($(this).html());
  });
});  

</script> 

 
</body></html>
```

My issue is that I have to click twice in order to get the mobile drop down menu for the website to either open or close. I believe that the JavaScript and HTML is sufficient.  I have not been able to modify this JavaScript so that it works properly. Nothing I have tried works. Any suggestions?  I have simplified this HTML to the essentials

Comment: post your javascript and html code to understand the problem, you also said that _" I am have not been able to modify this JavaScript so that it works properly."_ So please modify the question and highlight the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have very shared very little information. Possible reason can be that s.style.width is not 0px on initiation. Thats why the first click makes it 0px and the second click opens it. Try adding s.style.width='0px' at the start of the script.

Comment: I was not sure what this last person meant. I tried to make sense of their feed back but still no solution. This is a simple JavaScript problem. The latest attempt was to change the operator to != . Here is my failed attempt at the code:

Comment: I was not sure what this last person meant. I tried to make sense of their feed back but still no solution. This is a simple JavaScript problem. The latest attempt was to change the operator to != . Here is my failed attempt at the code:  <script type="text/javascript">

// Toggle close with button
var s = document.getElementById('side-menu');
function toggle_visibility() {
if(s.style.width != '0px')
s.style.width = '0px';
else
s.style.width = '300px';
}
</script>

Comment: Can you please provide the complete code so we can replicate your problem and identify the cause. The HTML code you provided has the opening tags for <nav><span><button><svg> elements but not the closing tags (</svg></button></span></nav>. Also the JS code you have provided discusses 'side-menu' element, but its HTML code is not provided. Please provide all HTML and JS code that has everything that can be possibly linked to the problem.

Comment: I am sure that the codes I posted would indicate that the nav  menu is a menu that slides in from the right.

Comment: Actually you have provided the structure HTML and JS code, but the path to the scripts and css style sheet you are using is not universal. Hence these resources cannot be loaded. Try adding complete url to these resources and run the code snippet on this page to see if the exact problem is replicated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the JavaScript (// toggle close ul after select from list) that is the at the bottom of the codes since it was clashing with the javascript (// Toggle close with button), which is also located near the bottom. I then used another JavaScript similar to the JavaScript found in (// Toggle close with button) to toggle close ul after a selection is selected from the list. This solved the double clicking issue.